# Error con ReturnType en modulo html2canvas

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

Hace relativamente poco en mi equipo de trabajo nos han asignado un nuevo proyecto con Angular. He de decir que todos teníamos conceptos muy básicos de Angular así que hemos ido aprendiendo sobre la marcha.

Ahora nos han solicitado que se impriman los registros que se muestran en pantalla en un pdf, por lo que hemos decidido (como el 90% de los usuarios de Angular) usar jsPDF y html2canvas para realizar esta tarea.

Hemos empezado incluyendo los módulos de cada uno con:

```
npm install jspdf
npm install html2canvas
npm install @types/html2canvas
```

Esto, nos ha dejado las versiones siguientes:

- jspdf ^1.5.3
- html2canvas ^1.0.0-rc.5

La cosa es que el compilador de visual studio nos está d**ando un error y marcándonos como incorrecto el fichero index.d.ts** alojado en ~\node_modules\html2canvas\dist\types\css\index.d.ts indicándonos que *no se encuentra el tipo **ReturnType***, concretamente en:

```
export declare class CSSParsedDeclaration {
backgroundClip: ReturnType<typeof backgroundClip.parse>;
```

He estado buscando artículos relacionados y mirando los casos abiertos y cerrados dentro de repositorio de git del html2canvas pero no he encontrado nada al respecto.

Al final "hemos supuesto que" ReturnType no es directamente de html2canvas, si no un elemento propio de TypeScript, por lo que hemos actualizado el módulo de TypeScript a la última versión, la ^3.7.2, pero, seguimos con el mismo error.

¿Alguien sabe qué podemos estar haciendo mal o por dónde van los errores?

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Te recomendaria borrar la carpeta entera de node_modules y el package-lock.json. Una vez hecho esto, ejecuta de nuevo npm install. Es posible que se te haya quedado en el cache de archivos la version incorrecta de alguna de las librerias.

Comment: Lo he hecho pero sigue el proyecto exactamente igual

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final he resuelto el problema. Por si a alguien le sucede lo mismo, el problema estaba en el lado del proyecto en Visual Studio.

El proyecto tiene en los paquetes Nuget una versión de Typscript 2.3, que es inferior a la que se usa en los modulos de Angular, en este caso, el módulo de Typescript es la versión 3.2.1.

Al actualizar el paquete Nuget de typescript en visual studio se ha resuelto el problema